# Trying Web API Dynamics 365 CRM - 403-Forbidden error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, webapi

I'm trying to follow some MS docs about using Web API for integrations with Dynamics 365 CRM, but I'm stuck as my organization uses a multi-factor auth method which is not easy to connect to.

I already tried using an app password in the code, but it failed.
Already have the app registered on Azure AD, permissions granted, manifest modified, secret-key generated.

Last try I did based on MS docs is

```
    `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using static System.Console;

    namespace CRM_WebApi
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serviceUrl = "https://MY-ORG.api.crm.dynamics.com";
            string clientId = "f8dea8ad-b993-4161-8743-***********X";
            string secret = "X*x*x*x*x*_lm2_DUo.0Dj_5_Wvkgu~eAY4";
            string redirectUrl = "http://localhost";

            AuthenticationContext authContext =
            new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY-ORG/oauth2/authorize");
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUrl, credential);
            //The access token
            string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
                client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  //2 minutes  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpRequestMessage request =
                    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/data/v9.1/WhoAmI");
                //Set the access token
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Get the response content and parse it.  
                    JObject body = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    Guid userId = (Guid)body["UserId"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Your system user ID is: {0}", userId);
                }

              }
            }
        }
    }`
```

This time I get the token, but get on the response 403-Forbidden.

> {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
> Headers:{  x-ms-service-request-id: 51067dc4-670c-4417-84b6-600044745e18
> x-ms-service-request-id: 04dd42b7-898d-4935-9c7e-20c1e7028a10
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
> includeSubDomains  REQ_ID: 04dd42b7-898d-4935-9c7e-20c1e7025b20
> AuthActivityId: fb3e62d9-4e1e-405f-846a-711e6ccc5555
> X-Source: 18921112101886374119914120471128195219221222118018411711623541331812331911702441x*x*x*
> X-Source: 2441011722446104156421301162318117713035251169236256193231163106232101179236129x*x*x
> Public: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST  Timing-Allow-Origin: *  Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 20:56:25 GMT
> Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=f439e98480c5c889aa462a387e36ac04f192110c01737e1e00da32e45cedx*x*;
> domain=MY-ORG.api.crm.dynamics.com; path=/;
> secure; HttpOnly  Content-Length: 89  Allow: OPTIONS  Allow: GET  Allow: HEAD  Allow: POST}}

Did anybody face a similar problem? Could you please guide me about to resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? If it's helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you are referring to this [Connect as an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#connect-as-an-app) to get the access token.

Please note that the docs states:

> When registering an app you follow many of the same steps described in
> Walkthrough: Register an app with Azure Active Directory, with the
> following **exceptions**:
>
> You do not need to grant the **Access Dynamics 365 as organization users**
> permission.
>
> This application will be bound to a specific user account.

So you don't need to add the delegated permissions in the Azure AD app. What you need to do is [Common Data Service user account bound to the registered app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#common-data-service-user-account-bound-to-the-registered-app) and [Manually create a Common Data Service application user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#manually-create-a-common-data-service-application-user).

After that, you can get the access token which has enough permissions.

Comment: And remember to give application user security role in order to access resources.